# RxJava - How to stop (and resume) a Hot Observable (interval)?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, stoppropagation, rx-java2

I have the following Hot Observable:

```
hotObservable = Observable.interval(0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                          .map((t) -> getCurrentTimeInMillis()))
```

However, I can't find a good way to stop it. I was able to partially solve this using `takeWhile` and a `boolean` flag (`runTimer`):

```
Observable.interval(0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .takeWhile((t) -> runTimer)
          .map((t) -> getCurrentTimeInMillis()))
```

There are 2 things I don't like in this approach though:

1. I must keep the flag `runTimer` around, which I don't want.
2. Once `runTimer` becomes `false`, the Observable simply completes, which means if I want to emit again I need to create a new Observable. I don't want that. I just want the Observable stop emitting items until I tell it to start again.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
hotObservable.stop();
hotObservable.resume();
```

That way I don't need to keep any flags around and the observable is always alive (it might not be emitting events though).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should the observable stop *producing* items, or continue operating but stop *emitting* them?

Comment: @npace Stop producing would be ideal, but I'd be happy with stop emitting only as well. Both works in my situation.

Comment: Kiskae's answer is perfectly valid, but just FYI.. if you would replace `takeWhile` operator in your previous solution with `filter` operator, you would get rid of the second disadvantage...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible approach uses a BehaviorSubject and a switchMap:

```
BehaviorSubject<Boolean> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(true);
hotObservable = subject.distinctUntilChanged().switchMap((on) -> {
    if (on) {
        return Observable.interval(0L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else {
        return Observable.never();
    }
}).map((t) -> getCurrentTimeInMillis());
```

By sending booleans to the subject the output of the observable can be controlled. `subject.onNext(true)` will cause any observable created using that subject to begin emitting values. `subject.onNext(false)` disables that flow.

The `switchMap` takes care of disposing the underlying observables when it is switched off. It also uses `distinctUntilChanged` to make sure it does not do unnecessary switching.

Answer (score 1):

Mybe you can use this

```
Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .takeUntil(stop)
        .subscribe(new MyObserver());

Thread.sleep(10000);
stop.onNext(-1);
```