# How to stop an interval on an Observable in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a specific situation where I'm using an RxJS interval, but at any given moment I may need to stop that interval. I assumed there was something easy like a cancel() or stop(). Similar to clearTimeout. This is possible to stop an interval once it's going? If not, what would be another approach.

Basically I have a large array that I'm stepping through. But there are external things that could happen that make it necessary to stop that step through and continue on to a new task. I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm just missing in the docs. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070443/rxjava-how-to-stop-and-resume-a-hot-observable-interval)

Answer (score 48):

> This is possible to stop an interval once it's going?

You can use the `.takeUntil` operator to complete an observable when some other observable emits. You'll of course need to set that other observable up to emit values in a way that is useful to you, but here's an example that stops an interval after 5 seconds:

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(100)
  .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(5000))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using **takeWhile**  `Observable.interval( 100 ).takeWhile( val => takeUntil ).subscribe( val => { ...`

Comment: Isn't this creating a timer multiple number of times  which is bad ?. The solution by @P.Huhn takes care of that i think or not ?

Comment: I am trying check if something is done, but after n tries give up.

Answer (score 47):

Just unsubscribe:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const subscription = interval(1000)
  .pipe(...)
  .subscribe();

...

subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Note that since `interval()` is asynchronous you can call `unsubscribe()` inside the `subscribe`'s callback as well.

Jul 2019: Updated for RxJS 6.

Comment: `subscribe` leads to imperative reactive code, particularly when the intent is to `unsubscribe`.  This is easier to construct at small scales, but harder to maintain at large scales.  E.g. https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87 recommends avoiding this.

Comment: I took the liberty of creating a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/ruzqty4k/8/) where you can see this solution in action.